# Update using Select Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I wanna write a query like this :

```
UPDATE `test_credit` 
SET `test_credit`.`credit`=(`test_credit`.`credit`-((`test_credit`.`credit`/100)*5)) 
WHERE `test_credit`.`name` = `users`.`uname`
```

in fact i want to get a query on `users`.`uname` = `test_credit`.`name` but mysql say it has error and realize `users`.`uname` as column

what is correct query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly join it with table `users`. As far from my understanding based on your query, you want to calculate the `credit` if the `names` exists on both tables.

Give this a try,

```
UPDATE  test_credit a
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON a.name = b.uname
SET     a.credit = (a.credit - ((a.credit/100) * 5.0)) 
-- WHERE  b.parent= "example"
```

Comment: if you have further questions, just drop a comment `:)`

Comment: tanx my friend it works and if i say a condition i should write like this?
UPDATE  test_credit a
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON a.name = b.uname AND b.parent= "example"
SET     a.credit = (a.credit - ((a.credit/100) * 5.0))

Comment: since it is using `INNER JOIN`, you can add it on `WHERE` clause, see my update.